# Google Fit DataSource Device (device that collects data) is null

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm using the Google Fit API on an Android phone. Subscribing to various data types and pulling the data from history works fine. I'm trying to get information about the device that recorded the data, i.e. the phone. According to the documentation, the DataSource has a getDevice() method, that returns "the device where data is being collected" - but the device is null. Why?

My code to access the device information:

```
 val request = DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .setTimeRange(from, to, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .enableServerQueries()
                .setLimit(DATA_POINT_LIMIT)

 request.read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)

 historyClient.readData(request.build())
     .addOnSuccessListener {
         data.dataSets.forEach {
             //it.dataSource //Data source is not null
             //it.dataSource.device //Device is null
         }
 }
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource#getDevice()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataSource` you get back corresponds to the merged `DataSource` for that `DataType`; it'll contain `DataPoints` for various origin `DataSource`s.

For a given `DataPoint` you can retrieve the origin `DataSource` using this method (subject to the caveats in the documentation): https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataPoint#getOriginalDataSource()